# Android Studio: “The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK” Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I realize that this question has been answered before.  None of my Android programming programs can link to to my java SDK directory.  I have already set up JAVA_HOME and check to make sure it points to my jdk1.7.0_05 and I get this error message.  What do I do?

Comment: Add jdk to PATH as well

Comment: Please do not write the error in the title, rather write it into the question.